# How to stop the css attribute font-size to get override from external style sheet universal selector

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I have something as mentioned below and universal selector for span to have "font-size=15"

```
<span id= "outer" style="font-size:72px;">
  <span id="Inner">text</span>  
<span>
```

Is there any way I can prevent universal selector to override my inner span with font-size =15
Here the span with id outer is dynamic and can have any value for font-size so I need something which wraps this whole output in some container and prevent any other css to get it override the font-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write like this:

```
#outer #Inner{
 font-size:15px;
}
```

OR

you can use `!important`  if nothing works.

```
span{
     font-size:15px !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the #Inner span should have the same font size as the #outer one it's contained in, you'll need to add

```
#Inner {font-size:1em}
```

to your stylesheet.
See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edk3h/).

Comment: these nested span's would be created by run time from Rich text editor and produces output as nested spans ,here the font-size can be dynamic  . so i need some way where the inner span will always take the font-size from outer span and never gets overridden by universal selector .

Comment: Ah, so in your example, the `#Inner` should be 72px, like `#outer`? That wasn't clear, sorry. In that case, you'll need `#Inner {font-size:1em}`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update . one more thing in this case if we dont have the ID attribute with span and then how it can be done ? also why font-size :1em ?

Comment: If the inner span doesn't have an ID, you can write `#outer span` for a selector. As long as it's more specific than the generic style for spans in the CSS. And `1em` simply means 100%, in this case, 100% of the font size in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can used this as like you

```
#outer span#Inner{
font-size:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code does not set font size for the inner `span` at all, so there is no question of override. So start with setting `font-size` on it.